# Скрытие полного изображения при открытие второго полного изображения

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать закрытие первой открытой картинки, если пользователь нажмет на вторую картинку?

Пример: Пользователь нажал на миниатюру - открылась полная картинка. Снова на нее (для её скрытия) он не нажал. Нажал на миниатюру второй картинки - скрылась первая полная картинка и открылась вторая полная. И так далее.

HTML:

```
<span id="doc_img_mini1" onclick="wall.doc_img_open('1'); return false">
    <img src="/mini.gif" class="zoom-img" />
    <div class="img-name">
        <div class="name">full1.gif</div>
        <div class="fl_r">159 КБ</div>
    </div>
</span>
<span id="doc_img_full1" class="no_display" onclick="wall.doc_img_close('1'); return false">
    <img src="/full1.gif" class="zoom-img" />
</span>

<span id="doc_img_mini2" onclick="wall.doc_img_open('2'); return false">
    <img src="/mini2.gif" class="zoom-img" />
    <div class="img-name">
        <div class="name">full2.gif</div>
        <div class="fl_r">1593 КБ</div>
    </div>
</span>
<span id="doc_img_full2" class="no_display" onclick="wall.doc_img_close('2'); return false">
    <img src="/full2.gif" class="zoom-img" />
</span>
```

JS:

```
var wall = {
    doc_img_open: function(did) {
        $('#doc_img_mini'+did).hide();
        $('#doc_img_full'+did).show();
    },
    doc_img_close: function(did) {
        $('#doc_img_mini'+did).show();
        $('#doc_img_full'+did).hide();
    }
}
```

И дополнительный вопрос: можно ли повесить анимацию загрузки при клике на миниатюру? Пока будет загружаться GIF-картинка - на ее миниатюре будет крутиться кружок.

Работать нужно с этим кодом, другой мне просто не подойдет, к сожалению.

Comment: 1. Так как вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к PHP, имеет смысл предоставить итоговый (отображаемый в браузере) HTML-код вместо смеси HTML и PHP. 2. Версия jQuery по-прежнему используется безбожно старая (1.4)? 3. Дополнительный вопрос - в отдельный вопрос. 4. _другой мне просто не подойдет_ - вы в этом уверены? Первое, что я бы сделал - избавился от устаревшего `onclick`. Причем даже если бы не использовал jQuery.

Comment: 1. Увы, исправить пост нельзя. Да и не зачем оттуда php убирать. 2. Так точно, 1.4.2. 4. Уверен на все 100%. Я поковырялся в движке и обнаружил, что все действия с js проходят именно так, иначе они просто не будут работать. Такие вот дела.

Comment: 1. Кнопка _"Править"_ по-прежнему на своём месте под метками вопроса. И это нужно - JS оперирует итоговым HTML-кодом, про PHP он знать ничего не знает. Мне не хочется фантазировать по поводу того, какие значения подставляются в HTML. 4. `addEventListener` (без jQuery) лучше `onclick` во многих аспектах, хоть и не поддерживается старыми IE. Но хотите `onclick` - будет `onclick`. Однако итоговый HTML-код без намёка на PHP всё равно нужен.

Comment: Увидел кнопку, исправил. Добавил еще одну картинку для ясности примера. Для меньшего геморроя лучше использовать то, что использует движок. Спасибо.

Comment: На здоровье. Я могу оформить отдельный (если автор текущего ответа его так и не исправит) ответ, если вы готовы принять его.

Answer (score 1):

Просто скрывайте ВСЕ большие картинки перед открытием новой:

```
doc_img_open: function(did) {
        $('[id^="#doc_img_full"]').hide(); //прячем все большие без разбору
        $('#doc_img_mini'+did).hide();
        $('#doc_img_full'+did).show();
    }
```

Comment: 1. Не `[id^="#doc_img_full"]`, а `[id^="doc_img_full"]`. 2. Допустим, была показана большая картинка у одного элемента. После чего вы нажимаете на миниатюру другой картинки. Все полные картинки скрываются, нажатая миниатюра скрывается, показывается полная картинки нажатой миниатюры. Проблема: миниатюра первой картинки так и осталось скрытой. Вопрос: почему вы не протестировали код перед размещением?

Comment: Вопрос, цитирую, был: "Как сделать закрытие первой открытой картинки, если пользователь нажмет на вторую картинку?" - на этот вопрос ответ дан исчерпывающий, код работает, первая открытая картинка скрывается, все по ТЗ. Что там происходит с миниатюрами - автор либо разберется сам (кто-то тут недавно агитировал за обучающую роль SO), либо задаст еще один вопрос. Или в качестве ответа требуется допилить сайт до конца? Сходите лучше автору расскажите про то, что не надо два вопроса в одном задавать - пусть про гифку делает отдельный, как минимум.

Comment: Есть огромная разница между _допилить сайт до конца_ и _показать миниатюры_ (что более чем логично). Не хотите доделывать код - как хотите. Что мне лучше делать я решу как-нибудь без вас. Не говоря уж про то, что про вынесение доп. вопроса в отдельный я написал в комментариях к вопросу 9 часов назад.

Comment: Про доп.вопрос - пардон. Про доделывать код - это автору решать. Захочет - прокомментирует. На данный момент ни у кого нет уверенности, что мистер "да и незачем оттуда пхп убирать" вообще не забил на все и хотя бы собирается что-то пробовать.

Comment: Про второй пункт - да, решать автору. Но первый пункт является ошибкой независимо от мнения автора. И так как у меня нет желания размещать второй ответ, который будет отличаться от вашего на одну строчку (про второй _спорный_ пункт), то я весьма надеюсь, что вы исправите свой ответ по пункту 1. И, пожалуй, я оставлю [пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/au3pn1Ln/) тут, в комментариях.

Comment: Испугался комментариев, и не стал тестить код из ответа, тем более нет функции **doc_img_close**. @Regent, спасибо за код, все работает. А на счет картинки загрузки - создам тогда отдельный вопрос, спасибо еще раз.